# Which one is the best method when it comes to multicast (stub)?

Tags: cisco, multicast

I want to set my device to L3 mode (specifically, 3560X-S).

In particular, I want yo configure multicast.

Because I haven't been configuring as multicast, I'm here to ask you about multicast configuration.

**Topology:**
[image: topology.jpg]

As you can see in the topology diagram, there are three switch models, such as SG300, 3560X, 4500X.

The 3560Xs are IP base, and IP base has no option but to enable stub.

**First, situation:**

1. PC_1, PC_2 ..., whole PCs are using mDNS, so they use multicast.
2. Based on PC_1's traffic which is multicast, it doesn't pass the GW(4500X).

I guess that's because I didn't configure multicast anywhere else.

**Second, questions:**

1. When I configure the 3560X switches, can I use stub mode in multicast
   situation? (criterion on 4500X, these are different domain between left and right side.) If not, can I change from 3560X-S to E (IP base -> IP services)?
2. I know the stub is only used for top of the network? How can I
   say.. That is, stub switch is located in between 2 IP which are different domain.

I wondered whether you can understand because I don't know English well..

If you don't understand my expanation, please don't hesitate tell me.

--------------------configuration--------------------------

```
(**SG300** Telnet permit)
conf t
ip ssh server
ip telnet server



Telnet permit (All devices are same)

username cisco secret cisco
enable secret cisco
line vty 0 4
 login local
exit
!
line console 0
 password cisco
!

**<4500X_1>**
en
conf t
hostname 4500X_1
ip routing
int te 1/1
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.1 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/3
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.9 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/5
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.17 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/7
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.25 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/9
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.33 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/11
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.41 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/13
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.49 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/15
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.57 255.255.255.252
!
int lo 0
 ip add 192.168.50.1 255.255.255.255
exit
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 1.1.1.1
 network 192.168.200.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.50.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
!

**<4500X_2>**
en
conf t
hostname 4500X_2
ip routing
int te 1/1
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.5 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/3
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.13 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/5
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.21 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/7
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.29 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/9
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.37 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/11
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.45 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/13
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.53 255.255.255.252
!
int te 1/15
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.61 255.255.255.252
!
int lo 0
 ip add 192.168.50.2 255.255.255.255
exit
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 2.2.2.2
 network 192.168.200.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.50.2 0.0.0.0 area 0
!

**<3560X_1>**
conf t
hostname 3560X_1
vlan 5
exit
ip routing
int te 1/2
 description ## 4500X_1 ##
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.2 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
int gi 0/23
 description ## HSRP ##
 sw mo acc
 sw acc vlan 5
!
int lo 0
 ip add 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.255
exit
!
int vlan 1
 ip add 192.168.0.252 255.255.255.0
 standby 0 ip 192.168.0.254
 standby 0 priority 110
 standby 0 preempt delay minimum 30
 standby 0 track te 1/2 50
 no shut
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 3.3.3.3
 network 192.168.200.2 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.100.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!

**<3560X_2>**
conf t
hostname 3560X_2
vlan 5
exit
ip routing
int te 1/2
 description ## 4500X_2 ##
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.6 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
int gi 0/23
 sw mo acc
 sw acc vlan 5
!
int lo 0
 ip add 192.168.100.2 255.255.255.255
exit
!
int vlan 1
 ip add 192.168.0.253 255.255.255.0
 standby 0 ip 192.168.0.254
 standby 0 preempt
 no shut
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 4.4.4.4
 network 192.168.200.6 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.100.2 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!

**<3560X_3>**
conf t
hostname 3560X_3
vlan 5
exit
ip routing
int te 1/2
 description ## 4500X_1 ##
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.10 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
int gi 0/23
 description ## HSRP ##
 sw mo acc
 sw acc vlan 5
!
int lo 0
 ip add 192.168.100.3 255.255.255.255
exit
!
int vlan 1
 ip add 192.168.1.252 255.255.255.0
 standby 1 ip 192.168.1.254
 standby 1 priority 110
 standby 1 preempt delay minimum 30
 standby 1 track te 1/2 50
 no shut
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 5.5.5.5
 network 192.168.200.10 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.100.3 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!

**<3560X_4>**
conf t
hostname 3560X_4
vlan 5
exit
ip routing
int te 1/2
 description ## 4500X_2 ##
 no sw
 ip add 192.168.200.14 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
int gi 0/23
 sw mo acc
 sw acc vlan 5
!
int lo 0
 ip add 192.168.100.4 255.255.255.255
exit
!
int vlan 1
 ip add 192.168.1.253 255.255.255.0
 standby 1 ip 192.168.1.254
 standby 1 preempt
 no shutd
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 6.6.6.6
 network 192.168.200.14 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.100.4 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
```

Comment: Can you post the configurations for the 4500, 3560 and SG300?

Comment: I edited following your opinion.

Comment: You aren't running multicast routing. Multicast is stopped at a layer-3 boundary unless you enable it on the router.

Comment: However, I don't know how to configure it...
Is it easy to configure multicast setting?
Now, I've read the book about multicast, but it's really hard ..
There should be configured sparse mode, dense mode..
1. ip multicast-routing distributed
2. configuring mode
3. unicast configuration..???
ah ㅠ-ㅠ

Comment: A multicast tutorial is too broad for this site; it is a large topic. You really should understand it well before you just jump in and start configuring it.

Comment: Yes right..!
After searching the internet, there is a book which specialize in Multicast!

Ah Ron Maupin!
I have a question about version!
If I configure multicast, should I change the switch 3560X-S to 3560X-E ?
Maybe 3560X-S' version is IP base which is supporting stub.
However, 3560X was located in the top of broadcast domain, so it doesn't need to be changed to IP service version, does it?